# Igl error : undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, libigl

I am starting to use the igl library for 3d in C++, on my mac. As I followed the tutorial, an error appeared. The first exemple, basically just reading an OFF file, works fine. But the second one, using igl::viewer doesn't. Here is the code :

```
#include <igl/readOFF.h>
#include <igl/viewer/Viewer.h>

Eigen::MatrixXd V;
Eigen::MatrixXi F;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Load a mesh in OFF format
    igl::readOFF("/bunny.off", V, F);

    // Plot the mesh
    igl::viewer::Viewer viewer;
    viewer.data.set_mesh(V, F);
    viewer.launch();
}
```

and I just enter in the terminal :

```
g++ -std=c++11 -I path_to_librairies/eigen-eigen-07105f7124f9/ -I path_to_librairies/libigl/include/ -I path_to_libraries/glfw-3.1.2/include/ main.cpp -o Test
```

where path_to_libraries is a personal folder in which my libraries (igl, eigen, glfw) remain.

And the terminal returns dozens of errors like :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_glActiveTexture", referenced from:
      igl::viewer::OpenGL_state::bind_mesh() in main-805320.o
```

I also downloaded Eigen and glfw. All I did is a cmake in the glfw source folder.

Finalement, I should add that when I tried with Xcode, adding in the project the framework OpenGL (something I found on the internet) removed half of the errors (the one concerning igl::viewer::OpenGL) but some igl::viewer::Viewer ones remain.

Does anyone have any clue?

Comment: You are not linking with an OpenGL library? I don´t know how this is done on OSX (more of linux/windows kinda guy) but that is where I would start. Good luck

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You most likely need to link in a few of OS X's frameworks, according to [GLFW's docs](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/build.html#build_link_osx), adding

```
-lglfw -framework Cocoa -framework OpenGL -framework IOKit -framework CoreVideo
```

should fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks it helped ! I had 76 errors of that type, now 26. The remaining ones concern igl::viewer::Viewer::launch_something() like for instance :

    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
      "_glfwCreateWindow", referenced from:
          igl::viewer::Viewer::launch_init(bool, bool) in main.o

Comment: Now you're not linking the GLFW library itself. Look at the docs I linked, and add the flag `-lglfw` to link GLFW. And you would also have to add a `-L` flag, to tell the compiler where to look for the library.

Comment: Ok great it finally works ! (I also had to install glfw after the make, which I did not do first). Thank you very much.